# Drop Off Library into Dynamic Folder (subfolders)

Tags: sharepoint-online, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

I am using SharePoint Online. I am trying to create a Drop off library. I have a required "Customer" field. The idea is that I want the file to be moved to a subfolder within that customers folder. For example:

```
/Documents/Michael/Plans/Pdfs
```

Where "Michael" is the client. So if the user uploads a file, selects the content type as "Plans" customer as "Michael" and file type as "PDF", it moves the file into the correct location.

The issue I have faced is I can create a folder based on a column, but I can't create subfolders.

For this hypothetical situation I have set Destination to be:

```
/Documents
```

I have checked "Automatically create a folder for each unique value of a property:"

and have tried to set the folder to be:

```
%1/Plans/Pdfs
```

but it doesn't work because I'm not allowed to use / in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

It's by design that forder name is formated by %1-%2, and you could only select one single,required property.

When the folder is created:

%1 will be replaced by the name of the property

%2 will be replaced with the unique value for the property